# Conformal maps algorithm

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that will graph one-variable functions in the complex plane using conformal mapping.

I have searched for a good algorithm to graph conformal maps, but can't seem to find one.

Does anyone have tips on how to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are Keenan Crane's slides on conformal geometry. They have lots of background on the topic, and on slide 20 is a list of the names of some algorithms for conformal mapping.

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/Other/OverviewConformalGeometryProcessing.pdf

The list, for convenience:

least square conformal maps (LSCM)

discrete conformal parameterization (DCP)

genus zero surface conformal mapping (GZ)

angle based flattening (ABF)

circle packing

circle patterns (CP)

conformal prescription with metric scaling (CPMS)

conformal equivalence of triangle meshes (CETM)

boundary first flattening (BFF)